# How to Exclude properties file from jar file?

Tags: java, maven

I have a java application with the following project structure:

```
myProject
  |
  |----src
  |     |
  |     |--main
  |     |
  |     |--resources
  |           |   
  |           |--userConfig.properties
  |           |--log4j.properties
  |
  |---target
```

I am using `Maven` to build my project. I am using `maven` command to build jar file as follows:

```
mvn package -DMaven.test.skip=true
```

I want to exclude `userConfig.properties` file from my JAR file so I have updated my `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/userConfig.properties</exclude>
</excludes>
```

But it excludes from the target folder in which the compiled code resides.
And the application won't run because it is unable to find the `userConfig.properties` file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is not making any sense.  You say that you want to exclude a file, but then you say that your app doesn't work because the file is excluded.  So why did you want to exclude it in the first place?

Comment: Are you using the Spring framework?

Comment: Yes,Chris I am using Spring Framework.

Comment: Stephen,I am making jar file of my application with the use of Maven command which will generate target folder which will contain the code that will run my application.I want to exclude userConfig file from myProject.jar ,so that whenever user need he can change some properties value irrrespective of jar file.And i have included it in my project.

Answer (score 51):

I encountered this scenario as well. Basically, you want to be able to run your code locally from Eclipse using some **userConfig.properties** file that is readily accessible, such as inside `/src/main/resources`. Additionally, you want to provide a compiled executable JAR with an external **userConfig.properties** that allows the user to configure the application without cracking the JAR.

My implementation is as follows: running `mvn clean install` will:

- create executable JAR with the specified `mainClass`
- exclude all `.properties` files located in `src/main/resources` from the JAR
- copy project dependencies into a `lib` folder in your project root
- copy all `.properties` files located in `src/main/resources` into a `conf` folder in your project root. Note that this step is an optional convenience for your users of the JAR. You can require the explicitly create this file in the `conf` directory. This `conf` directory is effectively added to your runtime classpath via the manifest.
- add this `conf` folder to the manifest, providing access to it from your executable JAR

Using these Maven plugins in conjunction with each other in your POM configuration will give you what you need. As to the "best practices" of this solution; I'm not sure.

Using **maven-dependency-plugin** as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using **maven-jar-plugin** as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>                    
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>package.path.to.your.main.class.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Using **maven-resources-plugin** as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using this project setup, I can run in Eclipse using one config, and provide my users a properties file to configure, without properties stepping on each other.

Comment: I like the idea of executable jar with properly set classpath. Maybe you can check [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) also - I used that to create deliverable zip with same structure as you have (with exception, that my jar is not executable..yet (-; ) - so you can achieve the same, by replacing resources and dependency plugins with assembly...

Comment: THIS.IS.A.LIFESAVER.

Comment: this is the best solution for the use case

Answer (score 11):

You shoud take a look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/userConfig.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably already doing it correctly, depending on where you configured that exclude (check with `jar tf` what files really are in your jar). Most likely, you're running into trouble because the file is not on your classpath and thus your app can't find it. Try adding the directory with the resources file in it to the classpath.

You might want to put in some defaults and let the application read in its configuration from a predefined path, to avoid having to mess with the classpath.