# how to exclude some setting files from the jar file when using Maven?

Tags: maven

As the testing environment and the development environment are different, and testers may changed the setting files in src/lib, how can i set up Maven to make sure these settings are excluded from the file jar generated by Maven but are put in a certain folder?
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728993/how-to-exclude-poperties-file-from-jar-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src/lib` directory is not included in the artifact, unless you have explicitly told Maven to do so. If you are using these resources as test resources, you should put them underneath `src/test/resources` to avoid any possible mix-ups. Furthermore, you can have Maven profiles for you different kinds of tests, if you need so.

Answer (score 0):

The **src/lib** folder is usually not included into the created jar file.