# Build jar without resource

Tags: java, maven

I using maven and I want to make an excutable jar.
I put some config files in resources then I want just change in config file without rebuild jar file.
Are there any help?

- main

  - java

    - Main.java
  - resources

    - prop.properties
    - config.xml

Comment: no, i means build jar one time when i can change property or config in resource many time without rebuild jar again.

Comment: So you want maven to reuse the existing jar and only overwrite jar entires changed? Unfortunately you will have to write a maven plugin by yourself because no one ever wanted to do that before. Usually creating a new jar every build isn't consuming much resource and doesn't worth the efford of creating the maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks all, I found the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/8052376/6800040
it's correct what I want.

Answer (score 0):

add resources tag in your pom.xml
like this

```
<build>
  <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>${profiles.res}</directory>
```