# Spring Boot Profiles - excluding properties file in WAR file for non active profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot Profiles to pull in different properties depending on the environment specified (default and localhost). They work as expected but both the application.properties AND application-localhost.properties get pulled into the WAR file.

Is there a way to create the WAR file with only the properties file for the active profile? I would like to configure it so if active profile is set to default then application-localhost.properties is NOT packaged in the WAR file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728993/how-to-exclude-properties-file-from-jar-file)

Comment: By default, if the profile is not active, its properties should not be included. You might need to provide more info.

Comment: @lealceldeiro - the values in the localhost properties file are not read, but the physical file (application-localhost.properties) is packaged with the warfile. I would like the file itself to be left out when the profile is set to "localhost".

Comment: oh, I see, well, yeah, it is packed, but its values are not really used if the profile is not active

Comment: @lealceldeiro - Yes, I understand that the values are not used, I would like them not to be in the WAR file at all. The localhost properties file contains connection strings and passwords that I don't want packaged into the WAR for non-local deployments.

Comment: If you use gradle, you could make a task to run before the `war` task which removes that file from the files to be packed.

Comment: @lealceldeiro -  I'm using maven - it looks like there might be some tricks with the pom file, but I haven't figured it out yet. I was hoping with profiles it might be an easy way to configure it.

Comment: @Puneet - thanks, that link shows excluding a file but does not show excluding based on active profile. It did give me a hint in the right direction though. I think I want to research MAVEN profiles since Spring/Spring Boot Profiles don't appear to support the setup  I need.

Comment: @headlikearock the challenge I see in what you are trying to achieve is, you pack your properties file in build phase but your spring profile is selected during/after deployment at run time e.g, through system properties.

Comment: @Puneet - correct. I ended up using a combination of profiles. Maven to pull in properties file based on the profile and Spring profile annotations to call some code based on profile. A little tricky and I'm only dealing with two profiles at the moment. I may refactor if additional profiles are introduced.